# Pymongo - removing database tuples that do not have a specific attribute

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a mongodb database. I am currently writing a python script using pymongo to clean the data.
My dataset has an attribute 'country'. I am trying to remove all tuples that's 'country' attribute is not the United States.

I know how to use unset to remove attributes from a database, and I know how to delete an attribute using remove many.

```
mongo_collection.delete_many({"Country":""})
mongo_collection.update({}, {'$unset': {'Country':1}}, multi=True)
```

However, I cannot find any resources on how to remove all tuples that do not match a specific attribute value.
Any insight would be greatly appreciated!!!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass your condition (`$ne` --> not equal) to the `delete_many`

```
countries_fixtures = [
    {"Country": "FR", "other": "A"},
    {"Country": "US", "other": "B"},
    {"Country": "AT", "other": "C"},
    {"Country": "US", "other": "D"}
]

from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client.test_stack_088
db.test_stack_088.drop()  # Remove whole collection (to make sure test works)
for country_fixture in countries_fixtures:
    db.test_stack_088.insert_one(country_fixture)
# We should have 4 records in our test_stack_088 collection, right? RIGHT??
assert db.test_stack_088.count() == 4  

# Question's answer:
db.test_stack_088.delete_many({"Country": {"$ne": "US"}})  # <---- This
# Yep, the line above is the juicy part...

# Let's make sure, 100% sure it worked...
assert db.test_stack_088.count() == 2
for record in db.test_stack_088.find():
    print(record)
```

You can take a look to the comparison operators on [this link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-comparison/).